# Android Layout: position element below lowest view

Tags: android, android-layout

I've attached a picture to better illustrate what I'm going for.

I have two `LinearLayout`s positioned side by side. Both are able to expand vertically, using wrap_content. I would like to position another container (HorizontalScrollView) below whichever one has the greater height. It's currently set to go below the right-most column, as generally it is taller, but in some cases the ScrollView will cover up the content in the left-most column. Is there a way to set this in the .xml file or will I need to resort to setting this in my onCreate method?

[image: Example screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap together the two LinearLayouts in another Linear or Relative layout, something like that(just change the properties for the original 3 layouts as you have/need them) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>  
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLeft"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearRight"
>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearRight"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/frame"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to position another
>   container (HorizontalScrollView) below
>   whichever one has the greater height.

You have to set it programmatically in the `onConfigurationChanged` method. So that it can work properly after the device's orientation changes.